# Configuring Redis master-slave architecture in Gitlab CI (cross-service comunication)

Tags: redis, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to setup simple redis configuration with only 2 services: master and slave.

Here's part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` with master-slave setup:

```
integration:
  extends: .test
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"
  services:
    - name: redis:latest
      alias: "redis-master"
      command: [ "redis-server", "--port", "6379" ]
    - name: redis:latest
      alias: "redis-slave"
      command: [ "redis-server", "--slaveof", "slave-master", "6379" ]
script:
    - nc -z -v -w30 -n redis-master 6379 // fails to resolve hostname redis-master ...
    // wait for readiness of both databases
    // run tests
```

*It's simplified for the privacy reasons*

Since I need communication between those services I am aware that I need to use feature flag called [FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#network-per-build) which:

> create and use new user-defined Docker brdge network per build.

Aforementioned documentation states also that

> Both the build job container, and the service container(s) will be
> able to resolve each other’s hostnames (and aliases).

When it comes to connection between **redis-master** and **redis-slave** everything works as expected and slave properly synchronize with master but when I try to connect with them using their aliases inside script section it results in error:

`Could not resolve hostname "redis-master": Name or service not known. QUITTING.`

So the question is why I cannot use aliases in the script section? And if it's not possible how can I get their IPs so that I can ping them if they are ready for connection?

**Side note:**

What is even more interesting when I don't use *FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD* flag aliases works fine in the script section (but at the same time **redis-slave** cannot communicate with **redis-master** so that's why I cannot ommit this flag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nc command you are using `-n` option, which is, per man, does the following

> -n      Do not do any DNS or service lookups on any specified addresses, hostnames or ports.

So essentially you are turning off your dns searches, here is a little test to illustrate:

```
$ nc -z google.com 80; echo $?
0
$ nc -n -z google.com 80; echo $?
nc: getaddrinfo for host "google.com" port 80: Name or service not known
1
```

Removing `-n` should fix your pipeline